# How to pass in property into childcomponent?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a container that passes in an attribute called 'key' into the childcomponent:

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import Pack from '../components/Pack/Pack'

const PacksContainer = ({Packs, addToCart}) => (
    <div>
        {Packs.map(pack =>
            <Pack key={pack.id}/>
        )}
    </div>
)

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    Packs: [{id:1},{id:2}]
})

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps
)(PacksContainer)
```

The childcomponent Pack looks like this:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'

const Pack = ({key}) => (
    <div>
        {key}
    </div>
)

export default Pack
```

I was expecting the ids to display but there is nothing there? How can I display the ids from the parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'll try to access `key` prop, you'll get such a warning:

> Warning: Pack: `key` is not a prop. Trying to access it will result in `undefined` being returned. If you need to access the same value within the child component, you should pass it as a different prop

`key` is something that is controlled by React internals before your component gets created. It will never be among the properties passed to a components from the considerations that one can accidentally overload it or use it for something unrelated.

A good practice is considered to pass down the identifier as another prop, even though it might look redundant.

```
const PacksContainer = ({Packs, addToCart}) => (
<div>
    {Packs.map(pack =>
        <Pack id={pack.id} key={pack.id}/>
    )}
</div>
```

)

```
const Pack = ({id}) => (
  <div>
    {id}
  </div>
)
```